# Adjust scroll view's inset within a child view controller

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I got a view controller hierarchy with the following parent-child relationship:

```
UINavigationController (contains) MainViewController (contains) UIPageViewController (contains) UITableViewController
```

In the inner-most UITableViewController, I have `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInset` set to `YES`, however this setting doesn't seem to work. As can be seen in the screenshot below, the table view's `contentInset` doesn't seem to be adjusted with the navigation bar.

My goal is to have this table view's `contentInset` to be automatically adjusted with the outer-most navigation bar. If the navigation bar or the status bar is hidden, I want the content inset to adjust accordingly.

How can I do that? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UINavigationController adjust its child view controller's `topLayoutGuide` automatically.

In your case it is not being propagated down far enough.

If you make sure this `topLayoutGuide` makes it down to your table view controller then you won't have to set the `contentInset` manually.

Also, your view controller hierarchy seems overly complex (I don't know the details of your project). This simplified version of what you have will give you what you are after for free.

[image]

Comment: I have the same setup and I still have to adjust the top inset manually. Any directions?

Comment: Check that `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInset` is set on the view controller with the container view in it.

Comment: Turns out that when `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInset` is true, only the first subview of the view controller's view is explored to find a scroll view. In addition, it'll stop as soon as it finds a scroll view therefore if you have more than one container it'll work only for the first one. In my case I have a image view behind the container view thus the last is not explored for a scroll view and so it doesn't adapt the top inset. Only solution is manual inset adaptation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the outer-most UINavigationController is still accessible to the inner-most UITableViewController via its `navigationController` property.

Because the navigation bar's frame is accessible by the inner-most view controller, we can do something like this in its `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGRectGetMaxY(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame), 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView.contentInset;
}
```